# How to handle the address book in my application in an effective way

Tags: ios, algorithm, web-services, whatsapp

I am creating an app which using address book.I am sending all my contacts to server each time to get the list of contacts who all are using the app and I should get the notification for new users in my contacts.I don’t think it is an effective way(sending all contacts everytime).Can any one suggest me how to handle the scenarios like edit contact,delete contact.How to avoid the sending of all contacts to server each time when I am opening the app.Also suggest me an effective algorithm to make best app

Answer (score 0):

You could just send the changed contact to the server, use an additional field like, `status` and save this `status` from the last time you `sync` to server, if a contact created, or edited or deleted, you just need to change this field to `not sync`, and when you sending data to the server, send this not synced data to the server.